# Create shell with restricted amount of binaries

Tags: shell, environment-variables, path

during software build I would like to restrict/control the binaries available to the build process. My plan was to make a directory `BUILD_PATH` which I populate with symlinks to the actual binaries; e.g. `make` and `gcc` which I want to be available for the build, and then set the environment variable $PATH to this directory, i.e. something like:

```
mkdir /tmp/BUILD_PATH
pushd /tmp/BUILD_PATH
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc .
ln -s /usr/bin/make .
ln -s /usr/bin/cmake .
popd
export PATH=/tmp/BUILD_PATH
```

And then invoke my build from wherever, however it seems the default(?) binaries in e.g. `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are found anyway? My main shell is bash, but a csh solution is also appreciated.

Comment: If this is a GNU autotools project, then the `PATH` may well have been set by the `configure` script already. You may also consider building in a chroot.

Comment: This is general question - before build of e.g. GNU autotools, but also `cmake` and `python setup.py`.

Comment: Ok, so a chroot may be the best solution, or building in a container/VM.